# Formatting exam results to perform a t-test in R

Tags: r, dataframe, format, t-test

**Question Overview:** I have a dataset containing the results to a 15 question pre-instructional and post-instructional exam. I am looking to run a t-test on the results to compare the overall means but am having difficulty formatting the dataset properly. *An example portion of the Dataset is given below:*

```
             1Pre  1Post   2Pre  2Post    3Pre  3Post    4Pre  4Post
Correct          B    B        A    A         B    B         C    C
1                B    B        C    D         C    B         C    C
2                C    B        B    D         C    B         C    A
3             <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>        <NA> <NA>       <NA> <NA>
4                B    B        B    A         B    B         C    C
5                B    B        B    A         B    B         C    C
6                C    B        D    A         A    D         C    B
7                C    C        D    D         E    E         C    C
8                C    A        B    B         A    A         <NA> <NA>
```

**Objective:** I would like to match the "Correct" value to the values in the rows below for the test takers, such that a value of 1 is correct, and a value of 0 is incorrect. I have accomplished this using the following code:

```
for(j in 1:ncol(qDat)){
  for(i in 1:nrow(qDat)){
    if(qDat[i,j] == correctAns[1]){
      qDat[i,j]=1
    }else{
      qDat[i,j]=0
    }
  }
}
```

I would then like to run a t-test comparing the pre and post means in addition to comparing the difference between the pre and post scores from each question, however, I need to omit any data points with NA. Currently, my method does not work with any NA values and thus replaces them with zero. Is there any method of running these tests and simply omitting NA values? Thank you!

**The Desired Output:**

```
             1Pre  1Post   2Pre  2Post    3Pre  3Post    
Correct          B    B        A    A         B    B         
1                1    1        0    0         0    1        
2                0    1        0    0         0    1        
3             <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>        <NA> <NA>       
4                1    1        0    0         1    1        
5                1    1        0    0         1    1        
6                0    1        0    1         0    0        
7                0    0        0    0         0    0         
8                0    0        0    0         0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try passing the following argument to the t.test call:

`na.action = na.omit`

Something like:

```
with(qDat, t.test(`1Pre`, `1Post`, na.action = na.omit))
```

Comment: Thank you! This addresses the latter half of the issue. The problem now is converting the A,B,C,D characters to 0 and 1 if they match the correct answer value without losing the NA values. Do you have any suggestions there? Cheers!

Comment: @ZachEisner, you only need to remove the `test[is.na(test)] <- FALSE` in nate's suggestion and it'll do what you want

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

rewrote your loop - no need to worry to much about `NA`s as you treat them as `0`, we can simply test the results and after set `NA`s as `FALSE`:

```
test <- qDat == correctAns # or correctAns[1] depending on your needs
test[is.na(test)] <- FALSE
storage.mode(test) <- "integer"
test
#      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
# [1,]  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0
# [2,]  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# [3,]  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
# [4,]  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# [5,]  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
# [6,]  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0
# [7,]  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
# [8,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

with the data

```
set.seed(123)
correctAns <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 8, replace = TRUE) 
correctAns
# [1] "A" "C" "B" "C" "C" "A" "B" "C"
qDat <- sample(c(LETTERS[1:3], NA_character_), 8*2*4, replace = TRUE)
qDat <- data.frame(matrix(qDat, 8, 4*2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
qDat
  #     X1   X2   X3   X4 X5   X6   X7   X8
  # 1    C    A    C    C  A    B    A <NA>
  # 2    B    A    C <NA>  B <NA> <NA>    B
  # 3 <NA>    B    C    A  B    A <NA> <NA>
  # 4    B <NA>    C    B  B    B    B <NA>
  # 5    C <NA>    B <NA>  A <NA>    C <NA>
  # 6    C    C    A    A  A    A    A    B
  # 7    A    C <NA>    B  A    C    B <NA>
  # 8 <NA> <NA> <NA>    A  B    A    B    C
```

**Edit**

```
set.seed(123)
#  correctAns is a vector of length 30
correctAns <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 30, replace = TRUE) 
length(correctAns)
# [1] 30
# qDat is a dataframe of dimensions 106x30 
qDat <- sample(c(LETTERS[1:3], NA_character_), 106*30, replace = TRUE)
qDat <- data.frame(matrix(qDat, 106, 30), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dim(qDat)
# [1] 106  30

# still works
test <- qDat == correctAns
test[is.na(test)] <- FALSE
storage.mode(test) <- "integer"
str(test)
# int [1:106, 1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# ..$ : NULL
# ..$ : chr [1:30] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Implementing your first line of code I get the error `‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`. For reference, correctAns is a vector of length 30 (30 questions) and qDat is a dataframe of dimensions 106x30 (106 participants, 30 questions)

Comment: @ZachEisner I reproduced it with the dimensions you indicated, it still works - see the edit. Are you sure `qDat` is not `30 by 106` instead? Does `t(qDat)==correctAns` work?